# Ionic2/angular: how to know when 2 different observables are terminated?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

Kind of beginner question here: in an Ionic2 component, I have 2 different service calls using Observables:

```
  getTimelineEvents() {
    this.receiptsEventsRequestState = RequestState.Pending;
    this.chargesEventsRequestState = RequestState.Pending;

    this.miscService.getCustomerReceiptsEvents()
      .subscribe(
        (events: TimelineEvent[]) => {
         this.receiptsEventsRequestState = RequestState.Success;
         this.receiptsEvents = events;
         },
      );

    this.miscService.getCustomerChargesEvents()
      .subscribe(
        (events: TimelineEvent[]) => {
        this.chargesEventsRequestState = RequestState.Success;}
        this.chargesEvents = events;
      );

  }
```

I'd like to know when both `getCustomerReceiptsEvents` and `getCustomerChargesEvents` are successful sothat I can call another method (this method needs chargesEvents and receiptsEvents data).

Thanks.

Comment: How about making second service call on success of first service call?

Comment: Because I want both requests to be executed in parallel to keep speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for both observables to complete and get the values they emitted by using the [`forkJoin` operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html). They will still be executed in parallel.

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  this.miscService.getCustomerReceiptsEvents(),
  this.miscService.getCustomerChargesEvents(),
)
  .subscribe(([receipts, charges] => {
    console.log('Results', receipts, charges)
  })
```

Comment: Wow thanks it's very interesting! One problem: Currently, if one of both requests fails, the whole thing fails. How to do if I want to call my method if at least one of both requests is successful?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Probably the best bet to ask a new question.